# setting up my own name server

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, nameserver

I'm in the process of setting up my own name servers using BIND9, however I want to visualize the name server setup in relation to registrars and other name servers.

Say I have a domain www.mydomain.com

I setup my 2 name servers:
ns1.mydomain.com -> 192.168.0.1
ns2.mydomain.com -> 192.168.0.2

1) How does the world know that my name servers are now at ns1.mydomain and ns2.mydomain. I read about setting up glue records at my registrar. Could you please elaborate on this, i.e. once i setup these glue records, can I now use my name servers in NS records for any other domain?

For e.g. NS records for www.otherdomain.com -> ns1.mydomain.com/ns2.mydomain.com

2) Given I setup the glue records as mentioned above, do I "have to" update mydomain.com NS records to point to my name servers? Can I keep mydomain.com NS records pointing to my registrars name servers, however use ns1.mydomain.com/ns2.mydomain.com as name servers for any other domain I own?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

just what I spotted at a glance - I think you need to find the external ip of your server - 192.168.0.1 is an internal ip.

Comment: I just used 192. as examples:)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options for first question:

a) Have an external (other, providers',...) DNS server resolve ns1.yourdomain.com and ns2.yourdomain.com

b) Set up a GLUE record for those two addresses

Either way, everyone will be able to resolve your two dns servers addresses. (Ofcourse you'll need to use public IP addresses).

After that, you set up a DNS server on both servers, and you can add zones for other domains. So when you buy otherdomain.com, you just set up the DNS servers for that domain to point to ns1. and ns2.yourdomain.com, and ofcourse add the appropriate records to your DNS servers.